# Generate array of random two values of one array how this

Tags: php, arrays

I have an array of 10 values and I need 4 random values. How can I do it?

For example

```
$wordone=array('1'=>'one', '2'=>'two', '3'=>'three', '4'=>'four', '5'=>'five', '6'=>'six', '7'=>'seven', '8'=>'eight', '9'=>'nine', '10'=>'ten'); 

$random_keys_two=array_rand($wordone, 2);
echo $wordone[$random_keys_two[0]]."<br>";
```

*Show Result*

```
three
```

*refresh again result show*

```
five
```

---

But I want to show random result me:

2 in english " Two "

*refresh again result show*

5 in english " Five "

thanks

Comment: if you found answer that solve your question please mark it as accepted (the grey "v" mark" at the left of the answer)

Answer (score 1):

Since you only want to get one random word from your array each time you refresh there is no need to specify a number:

```
$random_key = array_rand($wordone);
```

Now `$random_key` is a random number (ie: key) from your associative array `$wordone`. So, you can use this information in your echo result:

```
echo $random_keys_two . " in English is " . $wordone[$random_keys_two] . "<br>";
```

So, compiling this all together your code should look like:

```
$wordone = array('1'=>'one', '2'=>'two', '3'=>'three', '4'=>'four', '5'=>'five', '6'=>'six', '7'=>'seven', '8'=>'eight', '9'=>'nine', '10'=>'ten'); 

$random_keys_two = array_rand($wordone);
echo $random_keys_two . " in English is " . $wordone[$random_keys_two] . "<br>";
```

Answer (score 0):

```
echo ucfirst($wordone[$random_keys_two[0]]).”<br>”;
```

Assuming you want Five instead of five. First letter capital?